# When Flashing Firmware, Do you need correct PDA, Etc

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

Please Help, I had a FPR lock and I removed it with a custom rom, I was following a tutorial and I needed a stock rom firmware for my model. I was reading something about you can get any Firmware but just need the right model, is that true . I'm not that good at phones and stuff so just look at this. On my custom rom this it what it comes up with
Model : SM-G930F
PDA : G930FXXU1APL3
Phone : G930FXXU1APJ1
H/W : MP.0700

Answer (score 0):

you can download the firmware from its official website

https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s7-edge/SM-G935F/

Comment: Hi. Thank you for finding time to contribute here. May I suggest you go through our [help/on-topic] to know what's  on-topic and off-topic here. The question concerned is an off-topic one and we do not encourage answering them, as they lead to waste of answerer's  time and deviates site's usefulness from its intended usage.

Comment: It's also important to note that the website you linked is **not** Samsung's official website. It's a third-party website hosting Samsung ROMs.

Comment: Good of you to link to those fucking scammers